# Changing a long url to short

Tags: .htaccess

How can I change

```
 www.example.com/index.php?page=2_4_home
```

to

```
 www.example.com/2/4/home
```

or

```
 www.example.com/2/4/home/
```

with htaccess? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1_$2_$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?:index\.php|)\?page=([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/? /index.php?page=$1_$2_$3 [L,QSA]
```